# PyQt5 app displaying incorrect special characters in statusBar on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

**Background Info:**

Using PyQt5 5.10.1 and PyInstaller 3.3.1 to package app on a Mac

**Problem**:

Let's say I open a file called `file:1.mp3` in my PyQt5 app. When the filename displays in a statusbar with the following code:

```
def songChanged(self, media):
    if not media.isNull():
        url = media.canonicalUrl()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(url.fileName())
```

The statusbar displays the filename as `file_1.mp3` (colon replaced with an underscore). Other special characters such as `ω` simply crash the app. The weird part is that *this doesn't happen when I run the .py script from source, but when it's packaged as a .app executable.*

**What I want to happen**:

I want to have the app's statusBar display the text as it should, without changing special characters. If I open `file:1.mp3` it should display it as it is in the packaged app's statusBar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, turns out I'm really stupid. The characters `/ \ : * ? " < > |` cannot be used in filenames. For some reason, my computer once allowed me to put them in my file names. More information can be found [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1144082&seqNum=5).